# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required

Tags: java, spring

When i run the following code i got the error " Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required" what is the error in my code?

EmployeeDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends AbstractHibernateDao implements EmployeeDao{
public Employee getSalaryDetails(Integer empId)
{
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getEmpSalaryDtls");
    query.setInteger("empId", empId);
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    Map map = (Map) query.uniqueResult();
    closeSession(session);
    return map;
}
```

AbstractHibernateDao.java

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
public Session getSession() {       
    HibernateTemplate template = this.getHibernateTemplate();       
    template.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
    return template.getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

Error message is:

```
"192.24.0.77" "sourcePrg" 2017-05-30 04:41:14 "org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn" "Context initialization failed"
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeDaoImpl' defined in file [D:\....\EmployeeDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:355) ~[spring-struts-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:296) ~[spring-struts-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn.init(ContextLoaderPlugIn.java:226) ~[spring-struts-3.2.18.RELEASE.jar:3.2.18.RELEASE]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158) ~[struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473) ~[struts-1.1.jar:1.1]
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:753) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) ~[weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:117) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
```

Now i got this error:

```
"org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn" "Context initialization failed"
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'EmployeeDao'; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EmployeeDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernateTemplate' of bean class [com.temp.EmployeeDaoImpl]: Bean property 'hibernateTemplate' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
 Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Comment: The stack trace should direct you to the exact function where the exception was thrown. Can you add the stack trace to the question description? Is it possible that `this.getHibernateTemplate()` returns `null`? have you tried to debug it and see the value of `getSessionFactory()`?

Comment: Your code is flawed in multiple ways and you are actually trying to work around the `HibernateTemplate` / `HibernateDaoSupport` . Either work with the framework or don't ...

Comment: trying to use HibernateTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `HibernateTemplate` has been discouraged since hibernate 3.0.1, which introduced support for contextual sessions (which was around 2008!). Nowadays you are encouraged/adviced to write a DAO against [the plain Hibernate API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight).

With that said rewrite your DAO to the following.

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

Now your actual implemented DAO

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends AbstractHibernateDao implements EmployeeDao{
public Employee getSalaryDetails(Integer empId)
{
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getEmpSalaryDtls");
    query.setInteger("empId", empId);
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    Map map = (Map) query.uniqueResult();
    return map;
}
```

There are a couple of assumptions made here.

1. You have proper transactions setup with a `HibernateTransactionManager`
2. You have an actual transaction from a service with `@Transactional`
3. You have enabled transactions with `@EnableTransactionManagement` or `<tx:annotation-driven />`.

With this Spring takes care of opening/closing the `Session` for you and you don't have to think about it anymore.

Comment: That simply cannot be the case IF you did **exactly** as mentioned here. The exception WILL occur if you still have a reference to `HibernateDaoSupport` (which I explicitly removed).

Comment: Well of course... You don't have the `HibernateTemplate` property anymore... Remove `<property name="hibernateTemplate` ... />` from your configuration (and make sure you have `<context:annotation-config />`.

Comment: Another thing is you are doing something very dangerous... You are mixing jars from different spring versions (3.2 and 4.3) you should never mix versions of a framework (regardless of the framework). In the end it will come back and haunt you... It will eventually lead to strange issues like (NoSuchMethodException, AbstractMethodException etc. etc.).